# right aligned \hrule, size based on text above (and below) in Plain TeX

Tags: xetex, plain-tex

I need an `\hrule` which is right aligned and the size is exactly equal to the text above it.

And the same for text below it.

Is such a thing possible outside of LuaTeX? I am using XeTeX.

EDIT: 
For example:

```
Line:1        aaaaaa
Line:2        ______ (hrule)
```

or

```
Line1:        ______ (hrule)
Line2:        aaaaaa
```

By size I mean horizontal dimension.

I'm looking for how to get it to work with single line text but ultimately I'm looking  for is pointers to the concept behind how `\hrule` works so I don't have to come back again with a minor modification :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add a bit more context how the rules relate to the text surrounding them? Should the text be single line/`\hbox`ed only or normal paragraph text? By size, do you mean height+depth or the current font size?

Comment: @siracusa I edited the question. Please let me know if there is anything else that needs to be made clear. 
Thank you for your attention to the question.

Comment: (This is a comment, because I'm not able to test.)  I would try `\underline{\phantom{<text>}}` and otherwise use the same coding as for the text on the separate line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\halign` (in disguise as `\ialign`)

```
\def\ruleabove#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\ialign{\strut##\cr\leaders\hrule\hfil\cr#1\cr}}%
}
\def\rulebelow#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{\ialign{\strut##\cr#1\cr\leaders\hrule\hfil\cr}}%
}

\ruleabove{aaaaaa}\qquad \rulebelow{aaaaaa}

\bye
```

[image]